# Hardware RAID not recognized by OS

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I have a new configuration with the following hardware:

- Motherboard: MSI Z270 Gaming Pro Carbon. Firmware is in the latest available version (E7A63IMS.180, 01/26/2018)
- RAID controller: LSI MegaRaid 9341-8i with 8 disks attached. Firmware is also in the latest version (6.36.00.2, Sept. 11, 2017)

The RAID card seems to work fine since I have been able to access its BIOS interface to create a RAID 5 volume with the 8 disks.

However Ubuntu 16.04 couldn't see the RAID volume during install, and after install the volume does not appear in the `/etc/sdx` list. It is thus not even detected by the `Disks` utility or `gparted`.

I have installed the latest driver for Ubuntu from the Broadcom website (`07.704.04.00-1`) as well as the latest version of `storcli64`, but the controller cannot be found:

```
$ sudo ./storcli64 show all
CLI Version = 007.0409.0000.0000 Nov 06, 2017
Operating system = Linux4.4.0-112-generic
Status Code = 0
Status = Success
Description = None

Number of Controllers = 0
Host Name = Fishbike
Operating System  = Linux4.4.0-112-generic
StoreLib IT Version = 07.0500.0200.0300
StoreLib IR3 Version = 15.02-0
```

It is quite strange since the RAID card seems to be detected by the system:

```
$ lspci | grep Mega
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS-3 3008 [Fury] (rev 02)
```

and

```
$ dmesg | grep mega
[    1.686647] megasas: 06.810.09.00-rc1
[    1.687057] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: FW now in Ready state
[    1.687426] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: firmware supports msix    : (96)
[    1.687428] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: current msix/online cpus  : (8/8)
[    1.687429] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: RDPQ mode : (disabled)
[    1.687477] megaraid_sas 0000:01:00.0: Current firmware maximum commands: 272 LDIO threshold: 237
```

I'm totally confused on what I should try right now. Does anyone have a suggestion ?

**UPDATE**

The more detailed output of `lspci` is:

```
$ sudo lspci -v
...
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS-3 3008 [Fury] (rev 02)
Subsystem: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS-3 3008 [Fury]
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Memory at df200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Memory at df100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Expansion ROM at df000000 [disabled] [size=1M]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [68] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [a8] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=97 Masked-
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [1e0] #19
Capabilities: [1c0] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [148] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
Kernel modules: megaraid_sas
...
```

Also it seems that the driver is not in `/sys`:

```
$ sudo find /sys | grep drivers.*01:00
```

returns nothing, while the same command with 03:00 finds the USB controller for instance.

**UPDATE 2**

I've tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 server, with the hope that the correct driver would be included. It's a fail, I have the exact same symptoms.

I have also tried with a different RAID card I had on a shelf (LSI megaraid 9240-8i controller) and have the same issue.

I start to think that there is an incompatibility between the motherboard and these RAID contollers. Did anyone had similar issues?

**UPDATE 3**

I've just seen this answer from MSI [here](http://www.overclock.net/forum/320-raid-controllers-software/1520199-lsi-9341-8i-sas-sata-raid-card-driver-fails-start-windows-7-64bit.html):

```
The 9341-4i and -8i are software raid controllers. It has to be able to     
allocate memory during boot up or the driver will not initialize. The 
system board must support Interrupt 15 (memory allocation). Many desktop 
and workstation boards do not support INT15. There is no workaround.
The better option is use a hardware raid model 9361-4i or -8i
```

Seem like a bad news.

Comment: Check with `lspci -v` that the driver is actually attached. Don’t just look at snippets of `dmesg` output, check the entire output. You can use `less` and search it with `/`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel B. I'm not sure what to search for in `dmesg`. The interesting lines seem to be the ones containing `mega` posted above; for instance I have no result when searching for `lsi` or `9341`.

Comment: You go to these lines and check the context. There might be related messages before or after. Of special interest is the storage detection phase.

Comment: @Daniel. Thanks for your comments. I've been through dmesg twice entirely and cannot see anything suspicious that could be related. I have to say that I'm not an expert though ... I've uploaded the complete dmesg output here, in case someone has the courgae to have a look: http://www.raphael.candelier.fr/Misc/dmesg.txt

Comment: You need to install drivers for the RAID controller. Or use the server edition that's likely to have them already.

Comment: @MichaelBay: As stated in the question, I already have installed the latest driver for Ubuntu from the Broadcom website (07.704.04.00-1). Do I need something else ?